# How formal should an article be?

Tags: creative-writing

I write articles, poems and essays but usually I tend to make them informal. My question is "**Is it ok to write in a new style or informal style**". Do I have to follow the normal rules of writing and keep everything in the format every other writer writes in? 
 By informal, I mean, my own writing style where I write in an abstract way.

 This is a [link](https://derangedwriterblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/09/a-simple-day-in-my-amazingly-exciting-life/) of how I write.

Comment: The style you write in is dictated by who you are writing for. Who are you writing for?

Comment: @MattEllen general audience. I want to write funny and dark articles separately. The targeted audience will be mostly teens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing for an audience. Your audience is *not* "everyone" or "general audience" or "teens". People are different, even teens are different, and there is nothing that every person likes. So your audience is always a subset of all people, and you need to (a) define that audience and (b) research what they like.

If you have done that research, the answer to questions such as "how should I write" are implicitly clear, because they are part of what you researched.

A certain target audience will be used to certain writing styles and expect to read those styles. Depending on the target audience, they will be open or not open to larger or smaller deviations from their habits and expectations.

---

The other apporach, of course, is to simply write how *you* like, and let your work find its audience. The difficulty with this is that you won't know where to publish your work (which publisher, which medium), how to market it (format, channel) and who to market it to. To get your work to its implied audience, you will have to analyse it (what did you actually write?) and research possible audiences (who likes that?).

So, no matter wether you write *for your audience* or *for yourself*, there is no way around finding out either what your audience likes, or which audience likes what you have.